# PHP execute multiple links by code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a couple of links that I need to execute by code:

Here's what it looks like:

```
http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?api_key=mykey&api_secret=mysec&from=me&to=somenumber&text=test1
```

I need to do some kind of look which will do it by code:

For example:

```
Start loop:

execute: 
http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?api_key=mykey&api_secret=mysec&from=me&to=somenumber&text=test1

execute:
http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?api_key=mykey&api_secret=mysec&from=me&to=somenumber&text=test1

end loop
```

Is this at all possible using php or php/javascript?

Comment: `file_get_contents`???

Comment: `$i=1;while($i<=2){file_get_contents('http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?api_key=mykey&api_secret=mysec&from=me&to=somenumber&text=test1');$i++;}`

Comment: with same parameters? `&from=me&to=somenumber`

Comment: Tried it but it's only sending it once..I then get error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Comment: `set_time_limit(0)` to remove time limit

Comment: for($i=0; $i<=; $i++) {
file_get_contents(ur link);
}

Comment: That worked with set_time_limit(0) added but strangely there's a 20 seconds delay between each link. Way too slow...wonder why that is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($sub_req_url);
$encoded = '';
// include GET as well as POST variables; your needs may vary.
foreach($_GET as $name => $value) {
  $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
  $encoded .= urlencode($name).'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}
// chop off last ampersand
$encoded = substr($encoded, 0, strlen($encoded)-1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $encoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

use CURL For execute your Link
$sub_req_url = "http://rest.nexmo.com/sms/xml?api_key=mykey&api_secret=mysec&from=me&to=somenumber&text=test1
"

Comment: here if you want to use GET Or Post Then use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $encoded); Otherwise remove it and simply call your url.